# Is there a reason to pass master to the __init__ in the super call?

Tags: python

If I want to set up a class to create a very basic GUI, using tkinter, is there any reason to pass `master`  to `__init__()`?

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        #The original example passes master to __init__()
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widget()

    def create_widget(self):
        '''put a button "Blank" with no fucntion in the GUI'''
        self.bttn = Button(self, text = "Blank")
        self.bttn.grid()

root = Tk()
root.title("simple GUI")
root.geometry('200x200')

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

versus

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Code runs fine with out master being passed
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.grid()
        self.create_widget()

    def create_widget(self):
        '''put a button "Blank" with no fucntion in the GUI'''
        self.bttn = Button(self, text = "Blank")
        self.bttn.grid()

root = Tk()
root.title("simple GUI")
root.geometry('200x200')

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be operations that require the main window to have access to the master root object. Your current application may work but it may not work in more complex examples. If tutorials recommend that approach then I think it's best to follow that.